# Is it ok to mix unit names in my USES clause?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Is is ok to have something like this?

> Uses SysUtils, System.Classes;

instead of

> Uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code will compile if you have included `System` in the project's unit scope names option. So in that sense what you are proposing is alright.

However, in terms of readability, it is surely better to settle on a policy and stick to it. Mixing and matching like this makes your code less clear, in my view.

Comment: About readability: this mix happens when you upgrade and old project (Delphi 7, XE) to newer versions of Delphi.

Comment: You are free to replace IDE added units like `System.Classes` with `Classes` if you prefer. For a pure VCL project then that's not a bad policy.

Comment: Please note that the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Unit_Scope_Names#How_to_Specify_Unit-Scoped_Unit_Names_in_Your_Code) mentions that partial qualified unit names can slow down compilation.